# mysql search for brackets

Tags: mysql, for-loop, search, brackets

To classifie the movies of some friends, i did create a mysql table. we decided to Name the movies as example "dirty.fingers.(2006)". somehow i cant find this title when i search for "title LIKE dirty.fingers.(2006) as the brackets are disturbing. i did split the search like "title REGEXP dirty.fingers AND tilte REGEXP 2006". now it did fail once i did try to add the movie fingers out of the year 2006; the db found it as dublicate.

is there a way to search a text with brackets. i Need to search with LIKE

i did try with fingers.\(2006\), also with fingers.?2006?... no success

in other words... at the moment i use 
    select * from filme where `Pfad_M` REGEXP '$parttitle' AND  `Pfad_M` REGEXP '$year'
as 
select * from filme where `Pfad_M` LIKE '$title'
is not working.
variables value are as example:
    $title = 'dirty.fingers.(2006)'
    $parttitle = 'dirty.fingers'
    $year = '2006'

Comment: Can you add a full query to your question which you have tried?

Comment: Are you putting your LIKE string inside quotes: `WHERE title LIKE 'dirty.fingers.(2006)'`. Strings go inside single quotes in mysql, leaving them unquoted will lead to all sorts of strange-seeming behavior. If your string is in quotes then there is no reason why this should fail as the parentheses are not a special character in the `LIKE` condition.

Comment: this i try to execute:

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=moviedb', '***', '***');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `filme` WHERE `Title` LIKE 'Frauen.(2006)'  "; 
    foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
    echo $row['Title']."<br>";
    }

Comment: well, even i search in phpmyadmin i can search for fingers.(2006) or
'fingers.(2006)' or
fingers.\\(2006\\) or
fingers.?2006? 
no1 of this did work